# IBM Watson Assistant: How to allow digressions from dialog node with a non-conditional child node?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I have created a chatbot based to answer some geometry questions on my site. Using the example in the IBM course on how to make it user-friendly, I have a welcome node ask for the user's name, which is then read in a child node which is always true ("If assistant recognizes:" true) using

`<? input.text.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + input.text.substring(1) ?>`

I then saw that most users ignore the question in the welcome node that asks for their name, and jump straight into asking a  question. I want to enable a digression to the node that answers the question, but in the dialog builder, the parent node won't allow  digressions because

> "This node’s children block digressions away - A child of this node
> conditions on anything_else or true, so it will always trigger before
> digression occurs."

And in the child node, digressions are not enabled because

> "This node has no children Digressions are not possible if a node has
> no children as the flow has already ended."

Any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for the name of the user, slots are the best option. Here's how you can prompt the user for their name if not provided

Before using Slots, I would recommend you to create an entity (@name) and an optional intent (#ask-for-name). Check [this article](https://medium.com/ibm-watson/detecting-names-and-locations-with-watson-assistant-e3e1fa2a8427) for more information on detecting names and locations with IBM Watson Assistant

- On the welcome node, click `Customize` and enable `Slots`. This adds a new section to your node.
- Under `check for`, enter the entity @name. Save the response in a context variable ($name).
- If there's no name in the response, prompt for a question `Please provide your name before asking a Geometry Q`
  [image]

Now, when you Try it. Here's what you see and also when you click `Manage Context`, you can see the name in the response is assigned to `$name`and now you can use $name in any other node to address the person

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What's the purpose of the  optional intent (#ask-for-name), if you are not using it in the dialog?

Comment: This is to be shown in the dialog in place of irrelevant. To be sure that there is right intent  rather than showing irrelevant